# How can I send Heartbeat to GCM Server

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

How can I send heartbeat to the GCM server . So that we could keep the connection alive.

I used the below code to send heartbeat to the GCM server.

```
mContext.sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.google.android.intent.action.GTALK_HEARTBEAT"));
mContext.sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.google.android.intent.action.MCS_HEARTBEAT"));
```

But it again delayed the message.

After a long idle state I sent a notification to my app and gmail app.
The Gmail app receives the notification within time and my app not.

How it is happened. AFAIK The GCM uses port 5228 to receive messages. Then Why gmail received the message on time and my app received message after a long time.

What should I do to receive the messages on time.

Comment: Tell the message to leave a few minutes earlier to avoid rush hour traffic? ... what do you mean by `"on time"`?

Comment: When I sent a mail, the Gmail app show the notification within no time.But when I send a notification to my app it take some time to receive the notification

Answer (score 0):

Couple solutions that come in to mind:

1. Did you try to set delay_while_idle flag to false?
2. You can force android itself to send the heartbeat by broadcasting the following intents.

   com.google.android.intent.action.MCS_HEARTBEAT
   com.google.android.intent.action.GTALK_HEARTBEAT

Hope this works for you.

Comment: First solution I done in the server side,
Second one is already mentioned in my question.. both are not worked for me.